# Sharing data between fragments with livedata. but, in the second fragment data doesn't observe

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm using livedata to sharing data between two fragments. but, the data in the second fragment doesn't observe at all, so i can't get the data.

**ViewModel**

```
    var selectedAttachment = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Attachment>>()
    private val attachmentList = ArrayList<Attachment>()

    private fun getExistingAttachmentPos(key: String): Int{
        return attachmentList.indexOfFirst { att -> att.name == key}
    }

    fun toggleAttachment(attachment: Attachment){
        val id = attachment.name
        val pos = getExistingAttachmentPos(id)
        if(pos == -1 ){
            attachmentList.add(attachment);
        }else{
            attachmentList.removeAt(pos);
        }
        selectedAttachment.postValue(attachmentList)
    }
```

Shortly, the data in the first fragment can be set and observable

**firstfragment**

```
    private fun observeHorizontalAttachment(){
        viewModel.selectedAttachment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<ArrayList<Attachment>>{
            if(it.size>3){
                Log.d("tag63", it.toString())
                wrapPlus3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                plus3.text = "+${(it.size - 3).toString()}"
                pendingAttachment.clear()
                pendingAttachment.addAll(it)
                (rvAttachment.adapter as AttachmentAdapter).setDataset(it)
            }else{
                pendingAttachment.clear()
                pendingAttachment.addAll(it)
                Log.d("tag3", "kurang dari 3 ${it.size}")
                wrapPlus3.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        })
    }
```

In the firstfragment data is exist/observable

**secondfragment**

```
   private fun attachmentObserve(){
        viewModel.selectedAttachment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<ArrayList<Attachment>>{
                Log.d("tag6",  it.toString())
                pendingAttachment.clear()
                pendingAttachment.addAll(it)
        })
    }

    private fun handleRvAttachment(){
        Log.d("tag61",  pendingAttachment.toString())
        rvListAttachment.apply {
            adapter = ListAttachmentAdapter(pendingAttachment)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        }
    }
```

In the second fragment the `selectedAttachment` doesn't observe at all (even 'tag6' doesn't debugged) so I can't get the data

Thanks.

Comment: make sure using the same ViewModel in these fragments?

Comment: yes, i use the same viewmodel

Answer (score 4):

`SharedViewModel` will work for you in this scenario. You can use like this following:

`FirstFragment` and same for `SecondFragment`

```
activity?.let {
        yourViewModel = ViewModelProvider(it).get(YourViewModel::class.java)

        yourViewModel.selectedAttachment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<ArrayList<Attachment>> {
            Log.d("tag6", it.toString())
            pendingAttachment.clear()
            pendingAttachment.addAll(it)
        })
    }
```

Where on the `activity` it can be used as it follows,
If you are observing on `activity`

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel::class.java)
```

There is also a direct replacement of `ViewModelProvider(this)` with this [`by activityViewModels()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#activityviewmodels) and can be implemented like [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

Comment: @AlifAl-Gibran, how did you use `ViewModelProvider`?? Please update post

Comment: sorry, can you descirbe the function of `yourViewModel = ViewModelProvider(it).get(YourViewModel::class.java)`  because i have inject my viewmodel variable at the beginning of class like
`private val viewModel: ChatListViewModel by inject()`

Comment: you will have to use `ViewModelProvider` with `activity` reference on `fragment` and this how it exactly works with `SharedViewModel`

Comment: i think your answer is correct but the next problem is i declare my viewmodel as inject() and many attribute are using it, so i can't redeclare my viewmodel as your answer

Comment: sorry i have 1664 lines of code, and many of them are using it

Answer (score 0):

I changing the declare method for declaring the view model from 
`private val viewModel: ChatListViewModel by inject()` to 
`private val viewModel: ChatListViewModel by sharedViewModel<ChatListViewModel>()`